# INSERT INTO from select statement except one field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to insert most of the values from a select statement except one field that I want to insert the value from `$_POST["user"]`? Do I need two queries to do so?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `TAB1` (name,category, brand, image_url,big_img)
        SELECT a.name,b.category, b.brand, a.image_url,a.big_img
        FROM `mTaB2` a INNER JOIN `mTab3` b
        ON a.tid = b.id 
        WHERE a.id = ?           
       ";
$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$users->bindValue(1, $_POST["id"]);
$result = $users->execute();          

...............

$sql = "INSERT INTO `TAB1` (user)
        VALUES(?)
       ";

$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$users->bindValue(1, $_POST["user"]);
$result = $users->execute();
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? Everything looks messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for two queries:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `TAB1` (user,name,category, brand, image_url,big_img)
        SELECT ?,a.name,b.category, b.brand, a.image_url,a.big_img
        FROM `mTaB2` a INNER JOIN `mTab3` b
        ON a.tid = b.id 
        WHERE a.id = ?           
       ";
$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$users->bindValue(1, $_POST["user"]);
$users->bindValue(2, $_POST["id"]);
$result = $users->execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would think that something like this would work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `TAB1`(user, name, category, brand, image_url, big_img)
        SELECT ?, a.name, b.category, b.brand, a.image_url, a.big_img
        FROM `mTaB2` a INNER JOIN `mTab3` b
        ON a.tid = b.id 
        WHERE a.id = ?           
       ";
$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$users->bindValue(1, $_POST["user"]);
$users->bindValue(2, $_POST["id"]);
```